# Putting game on hold

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am unable to play or manage game for a 3 week period as I will have no internet or iPad access. What are my options for my Clan and my fort?

Comment: Not much I'm afraid...

Answer (score 3):

As [@Elias Benevedes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189521/putting-game-on-hold#comment256711_189521) said:

> Not much I'm afraid...

---

As Clash of Clans is a online-only MMO, it does not have a pause button. The only way that you can do about this is:

1. Buy a shield. (But the most you can buy at a time is 1 week and 3 days. This can be longer if you continue to renew the 1-Day and 2-Day shields (14 days is the maximum for one single term).
2. Otherwise, hope for the best.
   *It'd be wise to spend all your resources first before you stop playing. As people will typically not attack those with little resources to loot. Otherwise, when you come back, you may find that all your resources have been stolen.*

Answer (score 2):

For your clan, promote a trusted member to leader. Make an announcement so that everyone is informed.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain tricks for putting the game online for what ever week you go away for.. but that would probably violate the terms of Clash of clans, and will also require you to keep your laptop at home where there is internet.